# Chicken and Beef stored in the freezer not entirely frozen - safe?

Tags: chicken, freezing, storage-lifetime, beef

Recently (four days ago), a friend gave me a large chicken leg and some beef chunks for me to use at some point to cook with. Both of them were raw, but totally frozen, when I received them.

I put them in the freezer of my small fridge (I am a college student studying in a foreign country) to keep until I decided to make something with them. However, I opened the small freezer door (it's one of those student fridges where the freezer is a small box at the top of the fridge - you have to open the main door to open the freezer) and realized that the meat was no longer totally frozen. The freezer itself is apparently still cold enough that there is still ice and frost on the walls and floor of the freezer, and most of the meat is still frozen as well. However, some of the edges are not frozen, and are actually quite thawed. They are still cold, though.

Is this meat safe to eat/cook with?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not completely frozen, then it will last roughly as long as meat stored in the fridge. So if "recently" was within the last 4-5 days, it's fine. If "recently" is more than a week ago, it should not be eaten.